# Integrate Vue 3 Vitest and Monaco Editor

Tags: vuejs3, monaco-editor, vitest

Do anyone have an idea how to integrate vue 3 with vitest and monaco editor? my code looks like this now: It actually works, but many of the styles look really buggy, that I am starting to believe, I am doing something wrong. when I want to use the property
Line Numbers: 'on', this does not work, I am unable to see the numbers of every line, I am getting a weird icon also in the top left and also the width does not look correct.

[image]

how it should look:

[image]

**CodeEditor.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="code-editor">
    <div ref="codeEditorBox" class="code-editor-box"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref, watch } from 'vue'
import { editorProps } from './monacoEditorType'
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor'
import editorWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker?worker'
import jsonWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/json/json.worker?worker'
import cssWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/css/css.worker?worker'
import htmlWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/html.worker?worker'
import tsWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker?worker'

export default defineComponent({
  props: editorProps,
  emits: ['update:value', 'change', 'editor-mounted'],
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    self.MonacoEnvironment = {
      getWorker(_, label) {
        if (label === 'json') {
          return new jsonWorker()
        }
        if (label === 'css' || label === 'scss' || label === 'less') {
          return new cssWorker()
        }
        if (label === 'html' || label === 'handlebars' || label === 'razor') {
          return new htmlWorker()
        }
        if (label === 'typescript' || label === 'javascript') {
          return new tsWorker()
        }
        return new editorWorker()
      },
    }

    let editor: monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor
    const codeEditorBox = ref()

    const init = () => {
      monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
        noSemanticValidation: true,
        noSyntaxValidation: false,
      })
      monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
        target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2020,
        allowNonTsExtensions: true,
      })

      editor = monaco.editor.create(codeEditorBox.value, {
        value: props.value,
        language: props.language,
        theme: props.theme,
        ...props.options,
      })

      editor.onDidChangeModelContent(() => {
        const value = editor.getValue()
        emit('update:value', value)
        emit('change', value)
      })

      emit('editor-mounted', editor)
    }
    watch(
      () => props.value,
      (newValue) => {
        if (editor) {
          const value = editor.getValue()
          if (newValue !== value) {
            editor.setValue(newValue)
          }
        }
      },
    )
    watch(
      () => props.options,
      (newValue) => {
        editor.updateOptions(newValue)
      },
      { deep: true },
    )

    watch(
      () => props.language,
      (newValue) => {
        monaco.editor.setModelLanguage(editor.getModel()!, newValue)
      },
    )

    onMounted(() => {
      init()
    })

    return { codeEditorBox, props }
  },
})
</script>
<style lang="postcss">

.code-editor-box {
  width: v-bind(width);
  height: v-bind(height);
}
.code-editor-box-language {
  @apply bg-color-surface-variant py-2 pl-4;
  width: calc(v-bind(width) - pl-4);
}

.code-editor {
  width: v-bind(width);
  @apply border-[1px] border-solid border-color-outline rounded;
}
</style>
```

**MonacoEditorTypes.ts**

```
import type { PropType } from 'vue'
export type Theme = 'vs' | 'hc-black' | 'vs-dark'
export type FoldingStrategy = 'auto' | 'indentation'
export type RenderLineHighlight = 'all' | 'line' | 'none' | 'gutter'
export type lineDecorationsWidth = 'number' | 'string'
export type lineNumbers = 'on' | 'off' | 'relative' | 'interval'
export type wordWrap = 'on' | 'off' | 'wordWrapColumn' | 'bounded'

// import type { editor } from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api'

export interface Options {
  glyphMargin: boolean
  codeLens: boolean
  automaticLayout: boolean
  foldingStrategy: FoldingStrategy
  renderLineHighlight: RenderLineHighlight
  selectOnLineNumbers: boolean
  minimap: {
    enabled: boolean
  }
  lineNumbers: lineNumbers
  lineNumbersMinChars: number
  lineDecorationsWidth: lineDecorationsWidth
  readOnly: boolean
  fontSize: number
  scrollBeyondLastLine: boolean
  overviewRulerBorder: boolean
  overviewRulerLanes: number
  wordWrap: wordWrap
}

export const editorProps = {
  value: {
    type: String as PropType<string>,
    default: null,
  },
  width: {
    type: [String, Number] as PropType<string | number>,
    default: '200px',
  },
  height: {
    type: [String, Number] as PropType<string | number>,
    default: '100%',
  },
  language: {
    type: String as PropType<string>,
    default: 'javascript',
  },
  theme: {
    type: String as PropType<Theme>,
    validator(value: string): boolean {
      return ['vs', 'hc-black', 'vs-dark'].includes(value)
    },
    default: 'vs',
  },
  options: {
    type: Object as PropType<Options>,
    default: function () {
      return {
        glyphMargin: true,
        codeLens: false,
        automaticLayout: true,
        foldingStrategy: 'indentation',
        renderLineHighlight: 'none',
        minimap: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        readOnly: true,
        fontSize: 16,
        scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
        overviewRulerBorder: false,
        overviewRulerLanes: 0,
        lineNumbers: 'on',
      }
    },
  },
}
```

**Example.vue**

It is already imported

```
      <code-editor
        :value="value"
        :language="language"
        width="500px"
        height="150px"
        @editor-mounted="editorMounted">
      </code-editor>
```

in my setup function I have this editorMounted const, which I also return:

```
const editorMounted = (editor: monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor) => {
  console.log('editor', editor)
}
```

**vite.config.ts** added

```
 optimizeDeps: {
    include: [
      `monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/json/json.worker`,
      `monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/css/css.worker`,
      `monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/html.worker`,
      `monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker`,
      `monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker`,
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Did you try putting all the imports and `self.MonacoEnvironment...` code inside main.ts before `createApp(App).mount('#app')`? I was able to get a working app with minimal setup using something like this: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/tree/main/samples/browser-esm-vite-react but using vue. I also used `import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';` in my editor component instead of `import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';` otherwise highlighting wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

To format this code, I use:

```
 /// on first initialization format code
      editor.onDidChangeModelLanguageConfiguration(() => {
        editor?.getAction('editor.action.formatDocument')?.run()
      })
```

But I still did not get the line numbers at the left